# JQuery issue on Ipad

Tags: php, ipad, codeigniter, jquery

I have a popup form on which a user provides a key to get access to the site. I validate the user provided key with Jquery. It is working fine on my local system but when I submit the form using ipad it does not work. The form is even nor submitted.

My Form  is

```
<form name="form" method="post"> 
   <div style="width:530px;">
       <input style="display:none; height:25px;" id="downloadkey" name="downloadkey" type="text" />
       <input style="display:none;" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $variable['QUESTION_BUTTON']['value'] ?>"/>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id ="box_id" value="<?php echo $box_id ?>" />
</form>
```

JQuery is

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function(e) {
                var key = $('#downloadkey').val();
                var box_id = $('#box_id').val();
                var dataString = {KEY:key, BID:box_id};
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/home/validate_key",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        if(msg=="false"){
                            alert("Your download key is either wrong or missing");
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#popupContact').hide();
                            $('#backgroundPopup').hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();      
            });
        });
```

In my controller the validate function is

```
function validate_key(){
    $key = strtolower($this->input->post('KEY'));
    $id = $this->input->post('BID');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
    $row = $query->row();
    $download_key = strtolower($row->downloadkey);
    if($download_key == $key){
       $_SESSION['download_key'] = $key;
       $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    }
    else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Do i need something special to make it working on ipad?

Thanks

Comment: "it does not work" is not a good problem description. What exactly happens? Does your jQuery function ever fire? Also make sure you activate the debug console in Safari's settings so you can see errors

Comment: The Jquery works fine on pc and laptop but on ipad when click on the submit button it does nothing. How can I debug it on ipad?

Comment: As said, activate the debug console in Safari's settings. Also a very primitive but possibly useful way is to set `alert()`s in the various points of your script, so you see if the function is ever called, whether the callback is ever triggered etc

Comment: It says Javascript error : XMLHttprequest cannot load http://localhost/home/validate_key. cannot make any request from null

Comment: Try changing `click` binding to `submit` to react on form submit and not on button click. So make it `$('form[name="form"]').submit(....);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.click() doesn't function properly on iOS.

Try using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or by binding other events like touchstart

Answer (score 0):

```
.bind("click touch tap", function(){
 // code
});
```

Is what I've seen used when dealing with iPad.
(It's not a CodeIgniter issue for sure.)